# Discord.js: can't read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I tried to make a bot, in this case channel create/delete command, w/o any knowledge of js (I hate myself for that) and something didn't go well

Here is the code:

```
}else if (args[0] === "delete") {
      console.log('deleting')
      let ch = message.content.split(`${bot.prefix}vchannel ${args[0]}`).join('')
      let fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r=>r.name === ch)
      if (fetchedChannel.type === "voice") {
        fetchedChannel.delete()
      message.channel.send(`Голосовой канал ${ch} удален`).then(msg=>msg.delete({timeout:5000}))
      console.log('delete complete')
      }
    }
    }
```

And there is the error:

```
(node:5216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I tried to remove `ch`:

```
}else if (args[0] === "delete") {
      console.log('deleting')
      let fetchedChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r=>r.name === args[1].join(''))
      if (fetchedChannel.type === "voice") {
        fetchedChannel.delete()
      message.channel.send(`Голосовой канал ${args[1].join('')} удален`).then(msg=>msg.delete({timeout:5000}))
      console.log('delete complete')
      }
    }
    }
```

but other error appears:

```
TypeError: args[1].join is not a function
```

Tried found a solution by myself but I failed

Please help, I'm going insane.

If more code needed, I can send it.

Also, my english isn't good and I can make mistakes, please forgive me for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, the error means there is no `channel` in `message.guild.channels.cache` that has `name === ch`, so `fetchedChannel` is `undefined`. It is the stablished result for *not found*.

In your second code, if `args[1]` is a string, you are trying to use an Array method, `join`, on a string that cannot be.

If you have a debugger, use it to trace variable changes and values. If you do not have one, use `console.log` to output the intermediate values.

Checklist:

- Is `message.content` a string that contains `${bot.prefix}vchannel ${args[0]}`? That line of code is just removing every occurrence of `${bot.prefix}vchannel ${args[0]}`, because you split and join with `""`.
- Is `args[1]` the string that you need?